# How do I replace the same word but different case in the same sentence separately?

Tags: java, regex

For example, replace "HOW do I replace different how in the same sentence by using Matcher?" with "LOL do I replace different lol in the same sentence?"

If HOW is all caps, replace it with LOL. Otherwise, replace it with lol.

I only know how to find them:

```
String source = "HOW do I replace different how in the same " +
                "sentence by using Matcher?"

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(how, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(source);
    while (m.find()) {
         if(m.group.match("^[A-Z]*$"))        
              System.out.println("I am uppercase");
         else
              System.out.println("I am lowercase");

    }
```

But I don't know how to replace them by using matcher and pattern.

Comment: Best way to do this is not to use regexes.

Comment: Can you post your solution? cuz I think using regex to do this is a bit inefficient...

Comment: Umm ... my solution?  I'm sorry but this is a Q&A site not a "please write code for free" site.

Comment: Oh ok thanks though: )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve your goal: (not necessarily the most efficient, but it works and is simply understood)

```
String source = "HOW do I replace different how in the same sentence by using Matcher?";
    String[] split = source.replaceAll("HOW", "LOL").split(" ");
    String newSource = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        String at = split[i];
        if(at.equalsIgnoreCase("how"))  at = "lol";
        newSource+= " " + at;
    }
    newSource.substring(1, newSource.length());
//The output string is newSource
```

Replace all uppercase, then iterate over each word and replace the remaining "how"s with "lol". That substring at the end is simply to remove the extra space.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solution, and it works really well : )

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a really dumb solution:

```
String result = source;
result = result.replaceAll(old_Word, new_Word);
result = result.replaceAll(old_Word.toUpperCase(), 
newWord.toUpperCase());
```